# String manipulation loops

Tags: python, string

```
for char in "1bc4":
    print(char)
```

How can I modify this loop so it considers each character in turn: if it is a letter, it should print it converted to upper case; otherwise, it should print "not a letter". I.e. it should produce the output:

```
not a letter
B
C
not a letter
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
cha = "1bc4"
for c in cha:
    if c.isalpha():     
        print(c.upper())
    else:
        print("Not a letter")
```